# List of algorithms not working with amsbook document class

Tags: errors, algorithms, amsbook

I am using `\listofalgorithms` in a document with `\documentclass{amsbook}`. It seems the two clash for some reason. When I run `pdflatex`, I get the following error message:

```
(./main.loa
! Undefined control sequence.
\@dottedtocline ... \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep 
                                                  mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep...
l.1 ...uction algorithm.\relax }}{11}{algorithm.1}

?
```

Below is a minimal code snippet that produces the error in question. If one comments out `\listofalgorithms` the code compiles just fine under `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`. Oh, and I get the error when I run pdflatex the second time, that is after `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\title{Example}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \listofalgorithms

    \chapter{Introduction}
        This is about homotopy theory.

            \begin{algorithm}
                \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                    \Procedure{ComputeY}{$X$}
                        \State \Return $Y$
                    \EndProcedure
                \end{algorithmic}
                \caption{Algorithm.}
                \label{algo:algo1}
            \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Any idea regarding what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide the minimal code, that reproduces this error?

Comment: @Rico, I have just updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

the ams document classes treat lists of "whatever" differently from the
definitions in the basic document classes, and thus with some of the
additional packages (like those for algorithms) that follow the method
of the `book` class.

if you add these definitions to your preamble, the form of the list of
algorithms should be compatible with the `amsbook` way of doing things.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\@starttoc{loa}{List of Algorithms}}
\let\l@algorithm=\l@figure
\makeatother
```